# What will use more memory

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

I am working on improving the performance of my app. I am confused about which of the following will use more memory: Here sb is `StringBuffer`

```
String strWithLink = sb.toString();
clickHereTextview.setText(
     Html.fromHtml(strWithLink.substring(0,strWithLink.indexOf("+"))));
```

OR

```
clickHereTextview.setText(
     Html.fromHtml(sb.toString().substring(0,sb.toString().indexOf("+"))));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of *memory* an expression such as

```
sb.toString().indexOf("+")
```

has little to no impact as the string will be garbage collected right after evaluation. (To avoid even the temporary memory usage, I would recommend doing

```
sb.indexOf("+")
```

instead though.)

However, there's a [**potential leak**](http://nflath.com/2009/07/the-dangers-of-stringsubstring/) involved when you use `String.substring`. Last time I checked the the `substring` basically returns a *view* of the original string, so the original string is still resident in memory.

The workaround is to do

```
String strWithLink = sb.toString();
... new String(strWithLink.substring(0,strWithLink.indexOf("+"))) ...
    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

to detach the wanted string, from the original (potentially large) string. Same applies for `String.split` as discussed over here:

- [Java String.split memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056389/java-string-split-memory-leak)

Answer (score 2):

The second will use more memory, because each call to `StringBuilder#toString()` creates a new String instance.

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.java.html

Answer (score 2):

## Analysis

If we look at [StringBuilder's OpenJDK sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuilder.java#StringBuilder.toString%28%29):

```
public String toString() {
    // Create a copy, don't share the array
    return new String(value, 0, count);
}
```

We see, that it instantiates a whole new String object. It places in the string pool as many new instances as many times you call sb.toString().

## Outcome

Use `String strWithLink = sb.toString();`, reusing it will retrieve the same instance of String from the pool, rather the new one.

Comment: ...or even better, don't call `sb.toString` for finding the index of `+` at all, just do `sb.indexOf("+")`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating new objects always take up more memory. However, in your case difference seems insignificant.

Also, in your case, you are creating a local variable which takes heap space.

Whenever there are references in more than one location in your method it good to use 
`String strWithLink = sb.toString();`, as you can use the same `strWithLink` everywhere  . Otherwise, if there is only one reference, its always better to just use `sb.toString();` directly.

---

Answer (score 1):

Check other people's answers, the second one does take a little bit more memory, but this sounds like you are over optimizing. Keeping your code clear and readable should be the priority. I'd suggest you don't worry so much about such tiny optimizations if readability will suffer.

Answer (score 1):

The less work you do, the more efficient it usually is.  In this case, you don't need to call toString at all

```
clickHereTextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(sb.substring(0, sb.indexOf("+"))));
```

Comment: Actually setText(String str) takes only string.

Comment: `substring()` only return a `String`