# Memory usage of a large substring?

Tags: java

Reading the source code for `String#substring` (Java 1.7) it looks like it reuses the character array, but with different offset and length. This means that if I have an giant `String` that I substring, the initial string will never be reclaimed by GC (right?).

**What's the easiest way to sure that the giant `String` is reclaimed?** I am running JavaSE-1.7.

(For the curious, I'll be writing a radix implementation in Java to reduce memory usage. The answer to this question is essential to avoid the radix tree using more memory than necessary)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081659/java-substring-memory-leak/20082582#20082582 look at the following.

Comment: Can you update your question with precise version of Java you are using?

Comment: Pshemo: Question updated.

Comment: @Ztyx If you want someone to be notified about your comment make sure to add `@nickOfThatPerson` in it. Anyway what I was asking about was more about release number. I am interested if it was before or after `Java 1.7.0_06` since this behaviour changed then to avoid storing original array which as you noticed couldn't be deleted by GC.

Comment: @Pshemo I see. Anyway, I'm running `Java 1.8.0_45-b14` locally.

Comment: Thanks for response. Actually in "*with precise version of Java you are using?*" I was referring to "*Reading the source code for String#substring (Java 1.7)*" because as I mentioned earlier this behaviour was different before `1.7.0_6` and after so technically `Java 1.7` could mean any version. So now there are two possibilities - you ware reading old version so you ware right about lack of possibility to GC old big array, so `new String(String)` should be answer, or you ware reading newer version and your assumption about GC was wrong so answer should point you to changes in Java 7u6,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For pre JDK 7u6 version**

You should use `String(String)` constructor in that case:

```
163  public String(String original) {
164      int size = original.count;
165      char[] originalValue = original.value;
166      char[] v;
167      if (originalValue.length > size) {
168          // The array representing the String is bigger than the new
169          // String itself.  Perhaps this constructor is being called
170          // in order to trim the baggage, so make a copy of the array.
171          int off = original.offset;
172          v = Arrays.copyOfRange(originalValue, off, off+size);
173      } else {
174          // The array representing the String is the same
175          // size as the String, so no point in making a copy.
176          v = originalValue;
177      }
178      this.offset = 0;
179      this.count = size;
180      this.value = v;
181  }
```

```
String s = "some really looooong text";
String s2 = new String(s.substring(0,3));
```

When you pass result of `s.substring()` to `String` constructor, it will not use `char[]` of the original `String`. So the original `String` can be GC. This is actually one of the use case when one should use `String` constructor. While in most of the cases we should use `String` literal assignment.

**For JDK 7u6+ version**

In Java 7, implementation of `String.substring()` has been changed, which now internally uses `String(char value[], int offset, int count)` constructor (which we had to use manually in older version to avoid memory leak). This constructor checks it needs original `String`'s `value[]` array or a shorter array would be sufficient. So for JDK 7+ using `String.substring()` will not pose memory leak issue. Please have a look at the source code [String.substring()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/String.java#String.substring%28int%29)

Comment: Interesting. My `String#String` constuctor looks like this: https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/7c08a2a0126a8f40c221 I'm running JavaSE-1.7.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That is because in Java7 they have changed implementation of `String.substring()`, which now internally uses `String(char value[], int offset, int count)` constructor. Please have a look at the source code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/String.java#String.substring%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

Original String will always be Garbage Collected if required. No one will object. Here is the partial code for `substring()` method (JDK 1.7.0_51):

```
return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == value.length)) ? this
       : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
```

So, this method is returning a brand new String object or if beginIndex is 0 then the originam String will be returned. I guess you are concerned about first case. In that case, it has nothing to do with the older one once it is created.

Comment: "Here is the partial code for substring() method:" from which version of Java is this code?

Comment: @Pshemo, I have updated the exact version. Thanks! I should have mentioned it.

Comment: Then your answer is based on code from version which already corrected problem mentioned by OP http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/. Back in old days `new String(int start, int end, char[] value)` would simply store `char[] value` in `substring` result: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#644 which prevents it from being GC.

Comment: Versions of Java starting from `7u06` are using this constructor http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/String.java#String.%3Cinit%3E%28char%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29 which actually copies passed `char[] value` into new smaller array which allows GC to remove original and big array.