# How to efficiently find a string between two given substrings?

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string and I know two unique substrings and which one precedes which. What would be the most efficient way of finding the string in between?
Right now I am doing this, which works well:

```
middleString = line.split(firstSubstr)[1].split(secondSubstr)[0];
```

I need to do this for every single line in a huge amount of big files and I don't find this way very elegant. I was wondering if there is another way to do this more efficiently and elegantly.
If this line were evaluated lazily, I assume the code would be very efficient, but I don't think that is the case for this expression. Assuming a string of hundreds of characters starting by **abc**, being **"a"** the first substring and **"c"** the second, the code would look for all **a**'s and **c**'s in the whole string before returning **"b"**.
Another possibility would be to write my own method, iterate the original string character by character until the first substring is found and then append all the characters until the second is found; but I think there should be a way simpler than this.

Comment: You can use Regex for this

Comment: if you know, that `b` is between `a` and `c` then just find `a` and search for `b`. In debug/verbose mode check that `b` is before `c`.

Comment: @Juan, If your question has been answered, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer, otherwise, please elaborate on what's still unclear.

Comment: @aioobe, I couldn't run your code, but it was because of some codification problems (I am using /€ or /$ to detect the € and $ symbols) which work in split but neither Pattern nor indexOf detected them that way, so I was getting some out of bounds errors. I wanted to change them to test your solutions and measure performance, I will do it soon, now you have reminded me :)

Comment: split takes a regular expression, so escaping $ makes sense there but not in the indexOf case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using `indexOf` instead of split, as follows:

```
String in = "abcdefghij";
String part1 = "cd";
String part2 = "gh";

int i1 = in.indexOf(part1) + part1.length();  // end of first match
int i2 = in.indexOf(part2, i1);               // start of second match

System.out.println(in.substring(i1, i2));     // "ef"
```

Here's one solution using regular expressions and capturing groups:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(part1)
                         + "(.*?)"
                         + Pattern.quote(part2));

Matcher m = p.matcher(in);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));  // "ef"
}
```

Regarding which one is fastest, I'd say it depends on various factors. Which JRE are you using? Would the same pattern be used over and over again (can you compile the regex once and reuse it)? Since the code is just a few lines, I suggest you simply experiment with it a bit, and profile if necessary.

---

Note that the solution you suggest:

```
middleString = line.split(firstSubstr)[1].split(secondSubstr)[0];
```

could have a devastating memory footprint. See this Q/A: [Java String.split memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056389/java-string-split-memory-leak)